# Setting up production postgres (createdb permissions)

Tags: postgresql

I'm setting up postgres on DigitalOcean. I've set PG envs. The 9s are obviously redacted data. To facilitate the ssl connection, `~/.postgresql/root.crt` exists.

```sh
# env | grep PG
PGPORT=99999
PGPASSWORD=9999999999999
PGSSLMODE=require
PGUSER=doadmin
PGDATABASE=auth_service_prod
PGHOST=private-db-postgresql-sfo9-99999-do-user-9999999-9.a.db.ondigitalocean.com
```

When calling `createdb`, it fails:

```sh
# createdb
createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "10.999.9.99", user "doadmin", database "template1", SSL on
```

I *can* connect to `psql`, though. I don't know enough about configuring postgres to allow `doadmin` to create a db, but hopefully here is some useful info:

```sh
# psql
psql (11.7 (Debian 11.7-0+deb10u1), server 11.8)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

auth_service_prod=> \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 _dodb     | Superuser, Replication                                     | {}
 doadmin   | Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS            | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}

auth_service_prod=> \l
                                      List of databases
       Name        |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-------------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 _dodb             | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 auth_service_prod | doadmin  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 defaultdb         | doadmin  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0         | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                   |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1         | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                   |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DigitalOcean doesn't allow `createdb` from postgres, apparently. I removed the code creating databases, and created them "manually" from their GUI. The app is now only responsible for managing the schema, not the database(s).